Spark job spilling data vs OOM
I am using spark sql to run sql jobs using 10G executor memory.
When I am monitoring using Spark UI, I can see that data is being spilled to Disk and Memory (expected doing some explode operations ).
Would like to know is there any upper limit for data spilling to Memory / Disk.
When a job goes to OOM error.

Last sentences vague. Pls be more precise.
